# Angular2 - Routing pages in the background

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Ok, here is the problem. I have an endpoint on my server '/ping' which checks whether it is on and if everyting is working. I want to be able to detect when something goes wrong and show a page to the users when it fails.
This is something that I wrote myself and seems to be working, but I was wondering if there was a better solution as I dont want to have such code in my AppComponent.

```
export class AppComponent {
    /* .. */
    constructor(){
        this.pingLoop()
    }

    isOffline = false;
    pingLoop(){
        this.apiService('/ping', () => {
            //All is good
            if(this.isOffline){
                this.router.navigateByUrl('home');                
            }

            this.isOffline = false;


            setTimeout(this.pingLoop, 1000);
        }, () => {
            //Error occured
            if(!this.isOffline){
                this.router.navigateByUrl('offline');
            }
            this.isOffline = true;

            setTimeout(this.pingLoop, 1000);
        })
    }
    /* .. */
}
```

Comment: In apiService get the response and check status code, if it is 500 then redirect to offline page

Comment: I think the approach is pretty ok (if you want a regular continuous poll - alternatively if you only care about this when user navigates - use a guard instead) just extract that stuff into a service instead of polluting the app component with it

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will just move out the code to a service.